# HashMap values are changing without telling them to

Tags: java, hashmap, training-data

I have a problem that I am unable to understand..

I am building a `HashMap called wholeSetHistory`.

I am building a HashMap with the same keys and values that wholeSetHistory has, called `wholeSetHistoryT`.

In a similar way I create two `HashMaps called wholeSetRates, wholeSetRatesT`

All HashMaps have this format `HashMap<String, HashMap<String, Double>>` .

I have this function that creates a train set

```
public void createTrainSet(HashMap<String, HashMap<String, Double>> wholeSetRates, HashMap<String, HashMap<String, Double>> wholeSetHistory){
    for(String fbid : wholeSetHistory.keySet()){
        ArrayList<String> locsBe = new ArrayList<>();
        HashMap<String, Double> locss = wholeSetHistory.get(fbid);
        HashMap<String, Double> locss2 = wholeSetRates.get(fbid);
        for(String loc : locss.keySet()){
            if(locss.get(loc)==1.0){
                locsBe.add(loc);
            }
        }
        ArrayList<Integer> randomNums = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i=0; i<2; i++){
            Random rn = new Random();
            int randomNum; 
            do{
                int range = locsBe.size() - 1 + 1;                    
                randomNum =  rn.nextInt(range); 
            }while(randomNums.contains(randomNum));
            randomNums.add(randomNum); 
            locss.put(locsBe.get(randomNum), 0.0);
            locss2.put(locsBe.get(randomNum), 0.0);
            wholeSetHistory.put(fbid, locss);    
            wholeSetRates.put(fbid, locss2);   
        }
        randomNums.clear();
    }  
}
```

So, later on I am using it like this

```
(... creation of wholeSetHistory, wholeSetHistoryT, wholeSetRates, wholeSetRatesT)
System.out.println(wholeSetHistory.get("1"));//1
createTrainSet(wholeSetRatings, wholeSetHistory, nearUserIDWithVisitedTrueValues);
```

That means that I am passing to the function as paramater only `wholeSetHistory`

Although, later I

```
System.out.println(wholeSetHistory.get("1"));//2
System.out.println(wholeSetHistoryT.get("1"));//3
```

**This is what happens:**

> The values that changes in  wholeSetHistory changes in wholeSetHistoryT too! 
>   For example, prints 2 and 3 are the same(!) and different from 1.

Any help is mych appreciated.

Comment: Are you saying you're putting the same references in two different maps and when you change it in one map it changes it in the other too?

Comment: yes! the two pairs of hashmaps have the same keys and values

Comment: Changing a reference's value to an object in one map will change it accordingly in the other map as well. Try some sample code to test that it actually is that way

Comment: Are you sure locss and locss2 are different hash maps, and you are not passing the same reference? Same goes for wholeSetRates and wholeSetHistory?

Comment: Thanks you guys I found the solution!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A reference points to a location in memory. If you add the same reference to two different data structures, altering the reference in one will also alter the other. They point to the same object in memory.

Comment: Are you saying that if two different hashmaps have the same keys, you can't change the value in one of them? And if yes, what should I do? Overide a method or something ?

Comment: The keys don't actually matter. If two different keys held the same reference as a value it would also change them both. What you need is independent objects to point the two different references to if you don't want the behavior you're experiencing. @IraklisBekiaris

Comment: Yes! I got it. Thank you so much. I changed the way I create wholeSetHistoryT. I created a new hashmap to put as value and not the same i put on wholeSetHistory. Chears mate :)

Comment: @IraklisBekiaris, always glad to help!

Comment: Also, nice thing to know from now on ;d

Comment: @IraklisBekiaris, indeed, it is essential!